# Shall we have MathJax?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

> For people not familiar with this name -- [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is a plugin which converts LaTeX math markup like $X_1^2$ into proper math notation, in this case [image].

On one hand equations may appear here too rare to justify it, on the other hand it might be useful for chemistry; maybe it is not a desired use of this system, but it is easier to type $H_2O$ than to fight with HTML subscript.

Comment: I  hope that equations on this site are not rare! There are many fields of biology that require math to have any reasonably coherent discussion. Although it's true that using it for molecular formulae may be an abuse.

Comment: My only complaint about it is that it seems to freeze up my browser (Firefox), and I have heard about it freezing up other people's browsers as well (IE, Opera, Chrome).  This is particularly evident at the Theoretical Physics site.

Comment: @Larian Very old hardware? The software is actually incredibly mature and stable so this sounds like an uncommon issue. If it persists then you should definitely file a bug on the MathJax developer site.

Comment: any idea how long this will take to implement? I had to resort to using an image in this question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2599/what-are-the-units-of-q10-temperature-sensitivity

Comment: this one too http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/can-i-estimate-leaf-temperature-from-air-temperature-what-other-information-wou

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, because to be frank, typing out any math without some sort of notation system in the Stack Exchange software is a pain. And I don't necessarily think it's "overkill". While some users might not use it a great deal, most of my work is either mathematical biology or mathematical epidemiology, and talking about predator-prey models, epidemic models, etc. - which don't really have a home to talk about their *substance* rather than their implementation outside of this site - is essentially impossible without typing out some math.

More to the point, deciding not to have it I think stakes out a somewhat dangerous position that this site isn't *interested* in questions regarding Biology that require heading into any math more complex than high school algebra.

Comment: +1, there's a lot of mathematics in higher-level biology. We want to promote those questions.

Comment: And let's not forget disciplines such as biochemistry, physical chemistry or molecular modeling!

Comment: lots of mathematics in ecology too!

Comment: +1,  \LaTeX support is essential to the this site. Without it, the scope of questions and answers will be limited.

Comment: My only complaint about it is that it seems to freeze up my browser (Firefox), and I have heard about it freezing up other people's browsers as well (IE, Opera, Chrome).  This is particularly evident at the Theoretical Physics site.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella The better solution of this problem is to send MathJax authors good bug reports rather than not-using it... I'm a heavy user of MathJaxed stat.se and I have never had any problems.

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations, you should now have MathJax implemented here!

[EDIT]: I almost forgot to include -- the TeX / LaTeX guides are all on meta.Math. If you'd like to experiment with the formatting, I suggest [using their Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: Thanks for enabling it. Could you also change the configuration to the one chemistry.SE uses? The mhchem package for chemical formulas would also be useful here.

Comment: @MadScientist Done! :)

Answer (score 4):

The basic gist is, a *demonstrated need* for MathJax needs to be shown before we can enable it. It's a heavy script that we have to load on every page, and on some machines it can cause a hefty loading time. So if it's extremely rare that it comes up in comparison to the bulk of questions on the site, we prefer not to enable it. Consider Stack Overflow, which we still avoid enabling MathJax, because it just has too much slowdown for how comparatively rare it turns up.

We'll be keeping an eye on this question for evidence for and against the implementation of MathJax.

Comment: "It's a heavy script that we have to load on every page, and on some machines it can cause a hefty loading time." - +1 for this. On math.SE, it's a given. For physics.SE, the necessity is demonstrable. Here... I don't see that many questions that require mathematical notation coming up soon, so I'm not sure if the performance penalty of MathJax is justified here.

Comment: Scripts are cached though...

Comment: I’m not convinced. You essentially have to load the script *once*. For the whole SE network. Scratch that, for all sites on the interwebs which include the MathJax script from their content delivery network. This once-for-all load time is entirely negligible.

Comment: See [my answer](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/244/590) when this question was asked for the Cognative Sciences SE site for some details concerning the misconceptions of the load that MathJax places on pages that don't include mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

We **should** have LaTeX support - there's no reason not to unless it burdens the system. That's why we **shouldn't** use MathJax, which is client-side and will increase the size of every fresh site load.

We should use a server-side option which produces SVGs and stores them. They have an excellent system at [Scienceforums](http://www.scienceforums.net), which they have open-sourced [here](http://blogs.scienceforums.net/capn/2010/08/26/releasing-ipblatex/). It's for IPB but could be easily adapted for SE 2.0.

Comment: “will increase the size of every fresh site load” – no, that is wrong. See my comment on Grace Note’s (equally wrong) answer.

Answer (score 3):

**As a compromise**, I'd like to point out [this tool](http://www.homeschoolmath.net/worksheets/equation_editor.php).  It allows you to enter LaTeX notation either directly or using buttons then download a rendered image.  It works in real time and can be included in answers by copying the URL location then inserting a picture as normal.

Whilst this is obviously not ideal for those used to entering LaTeX directly, it of course doesn't add to page loading times.

Comment: “it of course doesn't add to page loading times” – and neither does MathJax. See my comment below Grace Note’s answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like huge overkill for this site.  The only time I'd use it is when talking about biophysics stuff, but there's always Physics.SE.  Getting it enabled on EE.SE was like pulling teeth as the administration was fearful of the tremendous burden it placed on bandwidth.

`<sub>` and `&rightarrow;` seems fine to satisfy most casual chemical conversations.

Comment: How would it be overkill? It is already implemented in many SO (so it should be easy to add it to this, I guess), and it won't prevent to use `<sub>`. But it will definitely be welcome when talking of higher-level biology/chemistry.

Comment: I don't think it would be overkill or rarely used. Mathematical notation is essential for most serious discussions of ecology.

Comment: @nico echoing Grace Note, if there is a need, it can be enabled.  *Right now* it's putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: I just edited someone's answer to convert things like NH_3 to NH<sub>3</sub>, and it was quite a pain. MathJax might make this easier.

Answer (score 1):

Can I also point out it can be used to make much better tables than anything else we have?  I think we are limiting MathJax too much if we think of it solely in terms of equations.   I just discovered it was active last night and used it to make the table here:

[Factor causing Methicilin-resistance in MRSA?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9916/factor-causing-methicilin-resistance-in-mrsa)

If you look at the edits, you can see the ascii tables I was trying to make, but I think that came out much better.

Also is it highlighted somewhere other than this question that we can use Mathjax?  I have wanted to use it before and just assumed we didn't have it.  If it is highlighted, I certainly missed it.